# Pagination in reactstrap issue(updated)

Tags: reactjs, pagination, reactstrap

Here I have created the pagination(reactstrap) for the table. Backend has 100 data records. I display 10 records per page. It works fine as i change the page.I have written some code for displaying paginating numbers.Initially, It should display paginating numbers from 1-5. On clicking 5th page, paginating numbers should display from 6 to 10 and so on..  Please help me. Thanks in advance

```
import {getInitialUsers, getPageByPageUsers} from "services/userService";

const Users = () => {
 const [payloads, setPayloads] = useState({
  offset: 0,
  limit: 10,
  search: "",
  page: 1,
  rowsPerPage: 10,
  count: 0,
 });
const [start, setStartPage] = useState(0);
const [end, setEndPage] = useState(payloads.limit);
const [users, setUsers]= useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
 fetchInitialData();
}, []);
const fetchInitialData = async () => {
 try {
  let res = await getInitialUserRequests();
  setUsers(res.data.data)
  payloads.count = res.data.size;
  getPager(res.data.size, payloads.page); /* res.data.size means total number of records */
 } catch (err) {
  console.log("error")
 }
};
 const getPager = (count, page) => {
  let totalPages = Math.ceil(count / payloads.rowsPerPage);
 /* facing issues in the following conditions */
  if (totalPages <= 5) {
   setStartPage(1);
   setEndPage(totalPages);
  } else {
  if (page <= 5) {
    setStartPage(1);
    setEndPage(5);
  }
  if (page >= end - start) {
    setStartPage(end - start);
    setEndPage(end - start + 4);
  }
  if (page + 4 >= totalPages) {
    setStartPage(totalPages - 4);
    setEndPage(totalPages);
  }
  }
 };
const handleChangePage = async (e, newPage) => {
 payloads.page = newPage;
 try {
  let res = await getPageByPageUserRequests(newPage);
  setUsers(res.data.data)
 getPager(payloads.count, newPage);
 } catch (err) {
  console.log("error")
 }
};
return (
 <>
  <Container className="mt--7" fluid>
    <Row>
      <div className="col">
        <Card className="shadow">
          <CardHeader className="border-0">
            <h3 className="mb-0">Users</h3>
          </CardHeader>
          <Table className="align-items-center table-flush" responsive>
            <thead className="thead-light">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Username</th>
                <th scope="col">E-mail</th>
                <th scope="col">Phone Number</th>
               
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {users.length > 0 ? (
                users.map((user) => (
                  <tr key={user.id}>
                    <td>{user.username}</td>
                    <td>{user.email}</td>
                    <td>{user.phone}</td>
                   
                  </tr>
                ))
              ) : (
                <tr className="text-center">
                  <th colSpan="5">No Data Found!!</th>
                </tr>
              )}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
          <CardFooter className="py-4">
            <nav aria-label="...">
              <Pagination
                className="pagination justify-content-end mb-0"
                listClassName="justify-content-end mb-0"
              >
                <PaginationItem
                  className={payloads.page <= 1 && `disabled`}
                >
                  <PaginationLink
                    href="#"
                    onClick={(e) => handleChangePage(e, payloads.page - 1)}
                    tabIndex="-1"
                  >
                    <i className="fas fa-angle-left" />
                    <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </PaginationLink>
                </PaginationItem>
                {[
                  ...Array(
                    Math.ceil(payloads.count / payloads.rowsPerPage)
                  ),
                ].map((page, i) => {
                  if (i >= start && i < end) {
                    return (
                      <PaginationItem
                        className={i === payloads.page ? `active` : ""}
                        key={i}
                      >
                        <PaginationLink
                          tag="button"
                          onClick={(e) => handleChangePage(e, i)}
                        >
                          {i}
                        </PaginationLink>
                      </PaginationItem>
                    );
                  }
                })}

                <PaginationItem
                  className={
                    payloads.page ==
                      Math.ceil(payloads.count / payloads.rowsPerPage) ?
                    `disabled`:''
                  }
                >
                  <PaginationLink
                    href="#"
                    onClick={(e) => handleChangePage(e, payloads.page + 1)}
                  >
                    <i className="fas fa-angle-right" />
                    <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </PaginationLink>
                </PaginationItem>
              </Pagination>
            </nav>
          </CardFooter>
        </Card>
      </div>
    </Row>
  </Container>
  </>
  );
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

i usually use a simple mathematical formula for this

```
data?.slice(pageNumber * rowsPerPage, pageNumber * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)?.map((row, index){
<div key={index}>{row}</div>
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Suppose i have 10 pages. Each page displays 10 rows.. Datas are displaying properly on changing the page. I'm facing the issue in displaying the paginating numbers. Like initially it should display paginating numbers from 1 -5. On clicking the 5th page , it should display from 6 to 10..so on.

Comment: you can send the total number of items from the backend, then on the frontend, you can write the logic for pages